# How do I print an exception if error in code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If have a function were I request some data from a website but when I get an error I want to print the error and restart my code. But I don't know the exact code, can please someone help me? This is a code example:

```
import time
input1 = input("Blabla: ")

def repeat():
    try:
        if input1 == "123":
            raise "Error: 123"
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        time.sleep(5) # Wait 5 seconds
        repeat() # Rerun code

repeat()
```

When I run this code I get the error 'exceptions must derive from BaseException'. Can someone help me?

Comment: Don't use a recursive call to "restart your code". Use a loop, that's what they're for.

Comment: You also probably want to move `input1 = input("Blabla: ")` inside of your function (otherwise, this value never changes when you recurse)

Comment: Since you always catch the exception, and you only want to print it out, it might also make more sense not to raise an exception at all. Instead, you could just `print("Error: 123")` directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't just raise random strings as an exception. If you want to raise a general exception without defining a relevant type, just raise `Exception`, replacing:

```
raise "Error: 123"
```

with:

```
raise Exception("Error: 123")  # The "Error: " should probably be removed
```

Alternatively, if you can use a more specific error, do so. If `123` is invalid because the value is wrong, use `ValueError` instead of `Exception`. If there is some more specific reason, make a subclass to make it easier for others to catch, e.g. (at top level in the module):

```
class SpecialValueError(ValueError):
    pass
```

so you can do:

```
raise SpecialValueError("Error: 123")
```

and people can catch it specifically, or via plain `except ValueError:`, `except Exception:`, etc.

Comment: I somehow miss mentioning the `__str__()` method of the derived exception class, since *printing the exception* was asked for.

Comment: @guidot: I'm not sure what you mean by that. `BaseException` provides a useful default `__str__` (it's just whatever message you passed as the first argument); it's pretty rare that you need to define a replacement `__str__`, but there's nothing preventing it.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are printing the error object's `str` while you need to print it's representation

Try this:

```
def repeat():
    try:
        if input1 == "123":
            raise Exception("Error: 123") # You need to use an Exception class
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e)) # Notice I added repr()
        time.sleep(5)
        repeat()
```

### Exception's Representation vs Exception's String

String:

```
try: 
    raise Exception("Exception I am!") 
except Exception as e: 
    print(e) 
# Output: Exception I am!
```

Representation:

```
try: 
    raise Exception("Exception I am!") 
except Exception as e: 
    print(repr(e)) 

# Output: Exception('Exception I am!')
```

Comment: That's kind of a side issue from the OP's problem (failing to actually raise a real exception type). Why do you think the `repr` is needed? That would just add unnecessary quotes around the output.